# Kendoui comboBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

I have a razor page and I creating the Kendo combo control this way:

```
@(Html.Kendo()
                      .ComboBoxFor(model => model.GenderCode)
                      .Name("GenderCode")
                      .Placeholder("Choose Gender...")
                      .DataTextField("Text")
                      .DataValueField("Value")
                      .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>()
                             {
                                 new SelectListItem()
                                 {
                                     Text = "Male", Value = "M"
                                 },
                                 new SelectListItem()
                                 {
                                     Text = "Female", Value = "F"
                                 }
                             })
                      .Suggest(true))
```

But it is rendering this way:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Gender Code is required!" id="GenderCode" name="GenderCode" type="text" /><script>
    jQuery(function(){jQuery("#GenderCode").kendoDropDownList({"dataSource":[{"Text":"Male","Value":"M"},{"Text":"Female","Value":"F"}],"dataTextField":"Text","dataValueField":"Value"});});
</script>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="GenderCode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
After I did some more investigating, i saw that i was getting an error "Object [object Object] has no method 'kendoDatePicker'" and when i looked this up on Kendo Site this is what it said:

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/troubleshooting
*JavaScript error that Kendo widgets are unavailable or undefined
If jQuery is included more than once in the page all existing jQuery plugins (including Kendo UI) will be wiped out. Will also occur if the required Kendo JavaScript files are not included.
The following JavaScript errors will be thrown (depending on the browser):
TypeError: Object # has no method 'kendoGrid' (in Google Chrome)
TypeError: $("#Grid").kendoGrid is not a function (in FireFox)
Object doesn't support property or method 'kendoGrid' (in Internet Explorer 9+)
Object doesn't support this property or method (in older versions of Internet Explorer)*

So I checked my bundles and I dont see anywhere where I am doubling my jquery inclusions:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));

        // The Kendo JavaScript bundle
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo").Include(
                "~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.716/kendo.web.min.js", // or kendo.all.min.js if you want to use Kendo UI Web and Kendo UI DataViz
                "~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.716/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"));


        // The Kendo CSS bundle
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo").Include(
                "~/Content/kendo/2013.2.716/kendo.common.*",
                "~/Content/kendo/2013.2.716/kendo.default.*"));
```

**UPDATE 2**
I have swtiched around and tried this

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"));

            // The Kendo JavaScript bundle
            //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            //        "~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.716/jquery.min.js"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to re-check the dependencies.  From [this page](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies), for the combo box it requires jquery.js, which I don't see in your bundles.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the layout page had 2 script sections, one at the top and one at the bottom.  I commented out the one the bottom the error went away.

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        ...
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home")</p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("User", "Index", "UserView", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("API", "Index", "Help", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Pauper To President, Inc.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

      @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")*@
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
```